# Adding a link to a gentelella chart

Tags: javascript, gentelella

Here is my JS

```
if($("##mybarChart").length) {
    var f=document.getElementById("mybarChart");
    new Chart(f, {
            type:"bar",
            data:{
                labels:['#dateList#'],
                datasets:[
                    {
                        label:"Sales for the selected range",
                        backgroundColor:"##26B99A",                   
                        data:['#dataList#']
                    }
                ]
            },
            options:{
                    eventsClick: myEventListener,
                    scales:{
                            yAxes:[
                                    {ticks:{beginAtZero:!0}}
                            ]
                    }
            }
    })
}
```

It produces a simple bar graph.

Is there a way for me to add a url to each bar? I'd like to drill down to see more data